# JSON Rendering: How to include the opening bracket description?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some Ruby code that is putting out JSON like this:

```
def nearby
  #@bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:origin =>[params[:lat],[params[:lon]]], :within => 5)
  lat = params[:lat]
  lon = params[:lon]
  #@bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:within => 5, :origin => [45.580639,-122.677682], :order=>'distance')
  @bathrooms = Bathroom.geo_scope(:within => 3, :origin => [lat,lon], :order=>'distance')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @bathrooms }
    format.js   { render :nothing => true } 
  end   
end
```

The result is something like this:

```
 [{"ID":129,"access":"1","avail":"0","bathroomtype":"0","city":"PORTLAND","comment":"","country":"US","created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","directions":"The two bathrooms are in the long hallway at the back of the restaurant, past the bar.","distance":"2.94986114636676","lat":"45.539217","lon":"-122.661795","modifed":"0000-00-00","name":"Echo","postal":"97212-3727","slug":"echo-portland170","source":"","state":"OR","street":"2225 NE Martin Luther King Jr. Blvd"},
```

What I don't know how to do is to name the set? For example, after the first enclosing bracket I would like to name the set bathrooms. How can I do this is Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like @bathrooms is a list, so you can't assign keys to elements in lists. You'll need to make a map first. For example, if you only want the first element:

```
format.json { render :json => {:bathrooms => @bathrooms[0]} }
```

To set all list elements:

```
format.json { render :json => {:bathrooms => @bathrooms} }
```

Comment: That's looking better as the brackets now name the set as bathrooms. But,h ow do I specify all elements in the list? That is not just the first record?

Comment: Another win of old school technology :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
render json: { bathrooms: @bathrooms }
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't do it: I tried:
render json: { bathrooms: @bathrooms }

Comment: That doesn't look like valid ruby syntax. See my answer for an example.

Comment: It's a perfect Ruby 1.9.2 syntax... use good old hashrockets if you prefer

Comment: TIL Ruby 1.9.2 has become more Javascript like :)

Comment: True, Ruby is lighter this way, I like it, except when it comes to `foo: :bar` which looks weird